# Sending Map Object to Client from Server, ObjectOutputStream Error

Tags: java, object, client, server, objectoutputstream

I am new to using the ObjectOutputStream. I am attempting to send a map object to my client from my game server. However, when I try to send my map object the Server throws a java.io.notserializableexception. I am unfamiliar with debugging these issues. I would appreciate some expert assistance.
Below I will first have the console output, then the server code, then the client code.

```
The DPServer is now accepting connetions
Client Socket[addr=/192.168.0.11,port=65435,localport=30480] has connected!
Client: new DPClient
Server: Do I try and send a map?
java.io.NotSerializableException: dark_project.map.MazeCell
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at dark_project.server.DPServer.sendMap(DPServer.java:139)
    at dark_project.server.DPServer.run(DPServer.java:111)
    at dark_project.server.DPServer.main(DPServer.java:161)
Could not get input stream from Thread[Thread-0,5,main] say something helpful.
```

Server

```
public class DPServer 
{
  private static final boolean DEBUG = false;
  private static final int DPSERVER_PORT = 30480; 
  private static final int DPSERVER_THROTTLE = 250;
  private static Map map; //contains the map
  private static int mapDimensions;
  private static MazeCell[][] mazeCells;
  private ServerSocket serverSocket;
  private InetAddress hostAddress;
  private Socket socket;
  private ArrayList<DPClient> players = new ArrayList<DPClient>();
  private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
  private static String inputLine;
  private static boolean mapSent = true;

  /**
   * DPServer()
   * Basic Constructor 
   */
  public DPServer()
  {
    // Attempt to get the host address
    try
    {
      hostAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e)
    {
      if (DEBUG)System.out.println("Could not get the host address!");
      return;
    }
    //Outputs host address!
    if (DEBUG) System.out.println("Server host address is: " + hostAddress);
    //Attempt to create server socket
    try
    {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(DPSERVER_PORT,0,hostAddress); //<< 0 means default 
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
      if (DEBUG) System.out.println("Could not open server socket!");
      return;
    }
    //Socket was created! Yay.
    System.out.println("Socket " + serverSocket + " created.");
  }

  /**
   * run()Could not get input stream from Thread
   * Starts the server so it can begin accepting client connections.
   */
  public void run()
  {
    System.out.println("The DPServer is now accepting connetions");
    while(true)
    {
      // First looks to remove disconnected players
      for(int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) 
      {
        // If player returns a connection == false then player is purged
        if(!players.get(i).isConnected())
        {
          System.out.println(players.get(i) + " purge, connection was dropped!");
          players.remove(i);
        }
      }
      // Get a client trying to connect
      try
      {
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        mapSent = false; //need to make sure map sent is false here for when a new client connects
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {
        if (DEBUG) System.out.println("Could not find a client trying to connect. :(");
      }
      // Client has connected! Everyone is happy.
      System.out.println("Client " + socket + " has connected!");
      // Add client as a player to arraylist.
      players.add(new DPClient(socket));
      // Send Client Map
      try
      {
        if (mapSent == false)
        {
          System.out.println("Server: Do I try and send a map?");
          sendMap(socket);
          mapSent = true;
        }
      } 
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      // Sleep
      try
      {
        Thread.sleep(DPSERVER_THROTTLE);
      }
      catch(InterruptedException e)
      {
        System.out.println("DPServer has been interrupted!");
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * This sends the map to the client.
   * @param client
   * @throws IOException
   */
  private void sendMap(Socket client) throws IOException
  {
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    out.writeObject(mazeCells); //error here
    out.close();
    out.flush();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    //create map then run server
    map = new Map();
    mapDimensions = map.getCellList().length;
    mazeCells = new MazeCell[mapDimensions][mapDimensions];
    //creates a hard copy of the maze
    for(i = 0; i < map.getCellList().length; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < map.getCellList().length; j++)
      {
        mazeCells[i][j] = map.getCellList()[i][j];
        //System.out.println(map.getCellList()[i][j]);
      }
    }
    DPServer gameServer = new DPServer();
    gameServer.run();
  }
}
```

client

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class DPClient
{
  private static final int USER_THROTTLE = 250; // arbitrary number, will need
                                                // to revisit this.
  private Socket socket;
  private boolean connected;
  private InPort inport;
  private Map map;
  private static int mapDimensions;
  private static MazeCell[][] mazeCells;

  private class InPort extends Thread
  {
    private ObjectInputStream inFromServer;

    public void run()
    {
      try
      {
        inFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        try
        {
          System.out.println("Client: Server says "
              + inFromServer.readObject().toString());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      } catch (IOException e)
      {
        System.out.println("Could not get input stream from " + toString()
            + " say something helpful.");
        return;
      }
      // connected!!! :) everyone is happy now
      System.out.println(socket + " has connected input stream!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
      // client should do listening and send info to server here
      while (true)
      {
        try
        {
          Thread.sleep(USER_THROTTLE);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
          System.out.println(toString() + " has input stream interrupted.");
        }
      }

    }
  }

  /**
   * DPClient() Basic Constructor Creates a new client with the socket form the
   * newly connected client.
   * 
   * @param newSocket
   *          The socket from the connected client.
   */
  public DPClient()
  {
    Socket newSocket = obtainSocket();
    if (newSocket == null)
    {
      System.out.println("Error Detected");
      System.exit(-1);
    }
    DPClient ClientAndSocket = new DPClient(newSocket);
  }

  /**
   * DPClient(newSocket) Overloaded Constructor Constructor that creates a new
   * client with the socket form the newly connected client.
   * 
   * @param newSocket
   *          The socket from the connected client.
   */
  public DPClient(Socket newSocket)
  {
    System.out.println("Client: new DPClient");
    socket = newSocket;
    connected = true;
    inport = new InPort();
    inport.start();
  }

  /**
   * isConnected() Returns the connection status of the client.
   * 
   * @return the connection status of the client true or false
   */
  public boolean isConnected()
  {
    return connected;
  }

  /**
   * purge() Purges this client from the connection! Sets connected = false
   */
  public void purge()
  {
    try
    {
      System.out.println("You have been purged.");
      connected = false;
      socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println("Could not purge " + socket + "!");
    }
  }

  /**
   * toString() Returns the String representation of this user. Helper Method
   * 
   * @return A string representation
   */
  public String toString()
  {
    return new String(socket.toString());
  }

  /**
   * obtainSocket() Helper Function
   * 
   * @return socket. clientSocket used to connect to a network.
   */
  public Socket obtainSocket()
  {
    InetAddress hostAddress = null;
    Socket clientSocket;
    String input = null;
    try
    {
      input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
          "Please enter server address", "Server Selection");

      hostAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    }

    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
      System.out.println("Could not get the host address!");
      return null;
    }
    // Outputs host address!
    System.out.println("Server host address is: " + hostAddress);
    // Create new socket
    try
    {
      if (input == null)
        clientSocket = new Socket(hostAddress, 30480);
      else
        clientSocket = new Socket(input, 30480);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
      System.err.println("testClient Error: Could not open connection to "
          + "localhost" + " on port " + "30480");
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
    return clientSocket;
  }
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    DPClient testClient = new DPClient();
    //MainGameLoopTest.runGame();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not really read your code, but the error sounds very clear. The Map you are trying to send contains an instance of `dark_project.map.MazeCell`, and this class is not serializable. All classes you want to send over the network (or store raw in a file) need to implement `Serializable` :)

Comment: Ok, does this only apply to sending objects? Because I thought you could send data that was not serialized?

Comment: All you need to do is mark the object as `implements Serialzable` and Java will take care of the rest, but otherwise yes, if you want to use OutputObjectStream, it needs to know how to convert the object to bytes and back.

Comment: I implemented serializable to the objects that I was passing and everything passed successfully. Thanks!